# Why does my python function return an empty dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, mean

I am trying to write a function which would use a dataframe (dataf) I am working on. The
function should have two arguments: testcode and ID. I want the function to compute the mean of the third column (C) based on the first 2 columns.

This is what I have in simplified form:

```
def myfunc(dataf, testcode, ID):
    filtered = dataf[(dataf['test_code']==testcode) & (dataf['ID']==ID)] 
    mean= filtered['C'].mean()
    return mean

mean=myfunc(dataf,'a', 'b')
print(mean)
```

[image: My dataframe]

Result I want: **28** (average of 44 and 12)

When I print mean, it returns 'nan'.
I printed the variables testcode and ID inside the functions to check if they are being passed when I call the function and they return **a** and **b** successfully.

What am I doing wrong. Thank you in advance

Comment: Your test code is 'a'. There are no lines in your dataframe that match it. The `filtered` dataframe has no lines, and the mean of an empty dataframe is a `nan`.

Comment: I have made a few changes and it still gives me the same error (nan). Could you tell me where I am going wrong please

Comment: After changing 'C' to 'c', your example works for me, as written, and I get 28.

Answer (score 0):

you are looking at `df['c']`  ... but your dataframe screenshot looks like `df['C']` ... im suprised it didnt throw an error instead of returning nan